# Makefile not working: make: Nothing to be done for `all'

Tags: java, file, makefile

I am new to java and I am having issues with my makefile.

```
JAVAC=javac
sources = $(wildcard *.java)
classes = $(sources:.java=.class)

all: $(classes)

clean :
        rm -f *.class

%.class : %.java
        $(JAVAC) $<
```

I can't figure why it is not working. Thank you.

Comment: Are all your files already built?

Comment: I only have one java file but it contains 3 classes @immibis

Comment: And was it already compiled? Did you change it after it was compiled?

Comment: No it just showed nothing to be done @immibis

Comment: Was there anything for it to do?

Comment: To compile and run the code. Yes, there is, I can get output by simply typing javac Main.java but cannot get the makefile to work @immibis

Comment: Do you know the point of a Makefile is to *not* do things if they don't need to be done? If you've already compiled your code and haven't changed it, why would it compile it again?